# How to get builtin of the builtin command?

Tags: bash, command-line, unset

Out of curiosity, say you created this function:

```
cd () { echo 'hi'; }
```

Now, whenever you entered `cd` you'd get "hi" printed. In case, you wanted to use the original `cd` command, you could do the following:

```
builtin cd
```

But what if I also created this:

```
builtin() { echo 'haha, got ya!'; }
```

Now, how do you get the builtin command for either `builtin` or `cd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay first off don't override the `builtin` command, which I assume you're not doing on purpose. Given the fact that you can override all the builtins, I thought up a more ridiculous route:

```
#!/bin/bash

builtin() { echo "Ha"; }
cd() { echo "Ha"; }
pwd() { echo "foobar"; }

result=$(/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -c "\\cd /home/cwgem/testdir; \\pwd; \\ls" )

/bin/echo "$result"
```

Result:

```
$ bash test.sh 
/home/cwgem/testdir
test.txt
```

The idea here is to:

- Use absolute paths to functions which can't be overridden as a function (this of course goes under the assumption that you don't go messing around with `/bin/bash` and `/bin/echo`)
- Utilize the fact that `$()` is syntactic command substitution and I wasn't able to override that
- Calling `bash` with `--noprofile` and `--norc`, which are explicit in not sourcing in the usual files which might contain overrides
- Finally `\`'s are added in front of commands in case aliases are floating around

That said, all and all this hack was done out of academic curiosity and should not be applied in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered about the `unset` command while writing this question down. If anyone else wants to know, you can do:

```
unset builtin
```

and

```
unset cd
```

to make the original commands work as expected. If anyone has a way to do so without un-setting the methods, I'd be interested in knowing how.

Comment: Which can just be overriden, too: `unset () { echo 'Problem?'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `env -i` to strip off the environment with its aliases and functions:

```
builtin() { echo 'haha, got ya!'; }
builtin pwd
/usr/bin/env -i bash -c 'builtin pwd'
```